# Prevent automatic URL rewrites created that include category URL key in product URL

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

Whenever I create a new product, Magento automatically creates unnecessary URL rewrites that include each category and subcategory combination, that use the categories' URL keys in the product path. For example, for a product `product-name` with the categories:

`category
category > subcategory
category > subcategory > third`

...Magento will automatically create URL rewrites with the following request paths:

`/category/product-name
/category/subcategory/product-name
/category/subcategory/third/product-name`

...as well as also creating the in-use URL rewrite with request path:

`/product-name`

**My question is, even though I have the setting `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` set to `No` in:**

**`System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations`**

**...how do I stop these additional URL rewrites from being created automatically?**

Now, again, I realize that the site isn't linking to these additional paths anywhere on the site, but if for some reason a search engine picked up:

`http://example.com/category/subcategory/third/product-name`

...this would load! I'm nervous this will result in duplicate content being indexed by search engines. Since the `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` setting is set to `No`, and all links to the product on the site are pointing to:

`http://example.com/product-name`

...I want to stop Magento from creating these unnecessary URL rewrites automatically.

For reference, I tried truncating the `core_url_rewrite` table to zero (basically emptying it out) and reindexing the Catalog URL Rewrites in `System > Index Management`. This still results in Magento automatically creating these unnecessary URL rewrites.

Also, for reference, I am using Magento Community 1.9.1.

Please advise! Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its not only about canonical links the problem is mainly another: crawling budget. You dont want to waste your crawling budget so the unnecessary urls need to go.

You should modify every entry in core_url_rewrite by shell script which:

- is_system = 1
- product_id not null
- category_id not null

there you set:

- target_path = direct product url
- options = RP

Now you created 301 redirects to the real page and only have one problem left:

If a product has no category-product-urls no other urls will be created if the feature is turned off via backend config settings, this is what we want.
But if a product yet has category-product-urls and you add this product to a category still a new category-product-url would be created. So you need to change one method by rewriting/extending Mage_Catalog_Model_Url :

```
 /**
     * Refresh product rewrite
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $product
     * @param Varien_Object $category
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
     */
    protected function _refreshProductRewrite(Varien_Object $product, Varien_Object $category)
    {
        //FIX: DONT ADD CATEGORY-PRODUCT-URL - MIGHT HAPPEN IF CATEGORY-PRODUCT-URL EXIST YET FOR THIS PRODUCT
        if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('catalog/seo/product_use_categories')) {
            if ($category->getId() && $product->getId()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }

        parent::_refreshProductRewrite($product, $category);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that rather than trying to disable this built-in functionality, instead [turn on canonical links](http://siteolytics.com/enable-the-canonical-meta-tags-in-magento/). If you have an older version of Magento without this option, [there are other ways to implement it](http://theintegrationengineer.com/magento-seo-canonical-links/).

However, if one were still inclined to remove it, they could probably create an extension that extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url` to do something like this:

```
class My_Catalog_Model_Url extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
{
     public function refreshProductRewrite($productId, $storeId = null)
     {
         if (is_null($storeId)) {
             foreach ($this->getStores() as $store) {
                 $this->refreshProductRewrite($productId, $store->getId());
             }
             return $this;
         }

         $product = $this->getResource()->getProduct($productId, $storeId);
         if ($product) {
             $store = $this->getStores($storeId);
             $storeRootCategoryId = $store->getRootCategoryId();

             // List of categories the product is assigned to, filtered by being within the store's categories root
             // CUSTOMIZATION: Ignore product categories if the 'catalog/seo/product_use_categories' config setting is false.
             if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('catalog/seo/product_use_categories', $storeId)) {
                 $categories = $this->getResource()->getCategories($product->getCategoryIds(), $storeId);
             } else {
                 $categories = array();
             }
             $this->_rewrites = $this->getResource()->prepareRewrites($storeId, '', $productId);

             // Add rewrites for all needed categories
             // If product is assigned to any of store's categories -
             // we also should use store root category to create root product url rewrite
             if (!isset($categories[$storeRootCategoryId])) {
                 $categories[$storeRootCategoryId] = $this->getResource()->getCategory($storeRootCategoryId, $storeId);
             }

             // Create product url rewrites
             foreach ($categories as $category) {
                 $this->_refreshProductRewrite($product, $category);
             }

             // Remove all other product rewrites created earlier for this store - they're invalid now
             $excludeCategoryIds = array_keys($categories);
             $this->getResource()->clearProductRewrites($productId, $storeId, $excludeCategoryIds);

             unset($categories);
             unset($product);
         } else {
             // Product doesn't belong to this store - clear all its url rewrites including root one
             $this->getResource()->clearProductRewrites($productId, $storeId, array());
         }

         return $this;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that with a hack in a template when there is a simple select to change in the admin to activate canonical url ? SYSTEM >> CONFIG >> CATALOG >> SEARCH ENGINE OPTIMIZATION

Comment: @b.enoit.be - Good catch. The solution from that blog is only applicable to older versions without that option. I have updated my answer with a link to another blog that shows how to enable with the built-in option if that is available.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you. I was wondering what the setting for canonical metal links was for.

More to my original question however, is there a way to do what I'm asking, just purely on principle? The core Magento code causes these links to be created...surely this can be changed.

Comment: @ZacharyBeschler - everything can be changed. I updated my answer with an alternate solution that would probably do the trick.